# Opencart expand all checkout steps

Tags: javascript, opencart, checkout

Is there a way to expand all checkout steps in opencat? I want to put all 6 steps in just 2.

```
<div class="checkout">
<div id="checkout">
  <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_option; ?></div>
  <div class="checkout-content"></div>
</div>
<?php if (!$logged) { ?>
<div id="payment-address">
  <div class="checkout-heading"><span><?php echo $text_checkout_account; ?></span></div>
  <div class="checkout-content"></div>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="payment-address">
  <div class="checkout-heading"><span><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?></span></div>
  <div class="checkout-content" style="display: block;"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
<div id="shipping-address">
  <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?></div>
  <div class="checkout-content"></div>
</div>
<div id="shipping-method">
  <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?></div>
  <div class="checkout-content"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="payment-method">
  <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?></div>
  <div class="checkout-content"></div>
</div>
<div id="confirm">
  <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?></div>
  <div class="checkout-content"></div>
</div>
```

The content is JavaScript generated or something so I can't just add `display:"block"` to the content divs.

Comment: Can you give the link to the output?

Comment: Basicly any opencart theme.

http://demo.towerthemes.com/tt_vigo/index.php?route=checkout/checkout

Just add something to the cart and guest checkout)

Comment: check the quick checkout extension http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7382